# Duplicate rows for each value in columns

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel sheet that looks like this:

```
1   A   B   C
2   D   E   F
```

How can I convert it to:

```
1 A
1 B
1 C
2 D
2 E
2 F
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: And how would you like to accomplish this, ie formula, vba, or power query?  Also what version of Excel are you using?

Comment: I am using Microsoft 365 Apps for enterprise. I do not have any knowledge of vba or power query. Formula would be perfect, but I am open to every solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create a header row if you don't already have one. The names are not important.

[image: Step1]

---

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to open the PivotTable and PivotChart Wizard (there are other ways to do this), select "Multiple Consolidation Ranges" and click next.

[image: Step2]

---

Select "I will create the page fields" and click next.

[image: Step3]

---

Select your data range, click Add, then click Finish.

[image: Step4]

---

It'll create a new worksheet with a pivot table in it. Remove the Column and Row fields from that pivot table so all you have is a grand total.

[image: Step5Part1]

[image: Step5Part2]

---

Double-click on the number in that grand total (6 in the example) and it will create a new worksheet with the data tabulated the way you want. Delete the "Column" field and you're good to go.

[image: Step6]

Comment: You are a life saver. Thanks.